# Share my Windows screen to someone via their iPad web browser

Tags: windows, web-apps, ios, screen-sharing

In the past I've been able to share my screen with someone who views it on their iPad in their browser.

However, all the services I use (join.me, Teamviewer, Zoom.us) all now require that the iPad user installs an app.  This is a real speedbump. I deal with brain injured people and they often can't log in to and navigate the app store.

**Any suggestions of a purely web-based VIEWER for seeing my PC screen?**

Comment: Did you Google? The first 3 or 4 hits seem to be what you are looking for. If not, could you pelase explain why, as that will help us find what you do need.